# Android: Slide left to add another element to a list

Tags: java, android, list, listview, arraylist

I want to do a simple app that when the user swipes from right to left is able to add another object to an array of objects. For instance, in a app that compares the body fat percentage of different people, by swiping left you can add a new person to the list. By swiping right, you can go back to the previous added person. When you're done adding people you just press a button and all the persons are compared.

How could I implement such a behaviour? I imagine creating a view for each person is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android actually recycles views if you work with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Then what you can do is store the current value of the View and check the onSwipe if the newer value is less or is more than the previous value.

Comment: Thanks! I also found this tutorial soon after. [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)